# Sql Query to list all views in an SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, metadata

I need an sql query to enumerate all views (I only need the view names) of a specific database in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To finish the set off (with what has already been suggested):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.views
```

This gives extra properties on each view, not available from sys.objects (which contains properties common to all types of object) or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS. Though INFORMATION_SCHEMA approach does provide the view definition out-of-the-box.

Comment: Error -Invalid object name 'sys.views'. I was querying master DB.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
,name AS view_name
,OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID,'IsIndexed') AS IsIndexed
,OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID,'IsIndexable') AS IsIndexable
FROM sys.views
```

Comment: Source: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/29/sql-server-list-of-all-the-views-from-database/

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.objects
WHERE   type = 'V'
```

Comment: Try to avoid using the general "sys.objects" - use the more specific views instead - `sys.views`

Comment: @marc_s please could you explain why that's the case?

Answer (score 4):

Some time you need to access with `schema` name,as an example you are using AdventureWorks Database you need to access with schemas.

```
 SELECT s.name +'.'+v.name FROM sys.views v inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = v.schema_id
```

Comment: By far more helpful than the standard "sys.views". Not everyone dumps tables in the DBO schema

Answer (score 3):

Run this adding DatabaseName in where condition.

```
  SELECT TABLE_NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) AS 'RowNumber' 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
  WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'DatabaseName'
```

or remove where condition adding use.

```
  use DataBaseName

  SELECT TABLE_NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) AS 'RowNumber' 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select v.name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS iv
join sys.views v on v.name = iv.Table_Name
where iv.Table_Catalog = 'Your database name'
```

Answer (score 2):

Necromancing.

Since you said ALL views, technically, all answers to date are WRONG. 
Here is how to get ALL views:

```
SELECT 
     sch.name AS view_schema 
    ,sysv.name AS view_name 
    ,ISNULL(sysm.definition, syssm.definition) AS view_definition 
    ,create_date 
    ,modify_date 
FROM sys.all_views AS sysv 

INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sch 
    ON sch.schema_id = sysv.schema_id 

LEFT JOIN sys.sql_modules AS sysm 
    ON sysm.object_id = sysv.object_id 

LEFT JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS syssm 
    ON syssm.object_id = sysv.object_id 

-- INNER JOIN sys.objects AS syso ON syso.object_id = sysv.object_id 

WHERE (1=1) 
AND (sysv.type = 'V') -- seems unnecessary, but who knows
-- AND sch.name = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' 
/*
AND sysv.is_ms_shipped = 0  
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM sys.extended_properties AS syscrap
    WHERE syscrap.major_id = sysv.object_id
    AND syscrap.minor_id = 0 
    AND syscrap.class = 1 
    AND syscrap.name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support' 
)  
*/

ORDER BY 
     view_schema 
    ,view_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I thought I'd put this out anyway since I couldn't find a query that would give me ALL the SQL code from EVERY view I had out there. So here it is:

```
  SELECT SM.definition
  FROM sys.sql_modules SM
  INNER JOIN sys.Objects SO ON SM.Object_id = SO.Object_id
  WHERE SO.type = 'v'
```