# How do I get the list of all views present in a database and its record count?

Tags: sql-server

For a validation purpose, I want to get the list of all the views present in a database and its corresponding record count. Can someone please help me to query this in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903262/sql-query-to-list-all-views-in-an-sql-server-2005-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Query to list all views in an SQL Server 2005 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903262/sql-query-to-list-all-views-in-an-sql-server-2005-database)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to retrieve rows count returned from a view by reading system tables, because this information is not maintained in the metadata. Only possible way is to actually execute `select COUNT(*) from view_name`, because views can contain complicated logic and the data returned by them actually is allocated to other objects (e.g. tables). For tables for example, you can get this rows count from [sys.partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) DMV.

One workaround is to select the list of views and generate a dynamic query, which will execute select count(*) from each view and combine the results, but this could be quite heavy query.

Anyway, here is an example how to return a list of tables ('T') and views ('V') in your database. For tables you will also get a rows count, while for views this column will be null. Then change the where clause to return only views (`where o.type = 'V'`) and execute the query. Copy/paste the last column in new query window (removing the last union all) and execute it to return the rows count for each view (NOTE: It could take a long time and have significant impact on your server!).

```
select o.name, sum(p.rows) as RowsCount, o.type, concat('select ''', o.name, ''' as ObjectName, count(*) as RowsCount from ', o.name, ' union all ')
from sys.objects o
left join sys.partitions p on p.object_id = o.object_id
where o.type in ('U', 'V')
group by o.name, o.type
order by o.name
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Andrey Nikolov (Only possible way is to actually execute `select COUNT(*) from view_name`), the query below retrieves a list of views in a database along with the number of records and columns corresponding to each view:

```
USE YourDatabaseName;

-- Create temp table to save results
CREATE TABLE #ViewRecordCount (ViewName NVARCHAR(128), RecordCount INT);

-- Retrive list of views from database
DECLARE @viewName NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE viewCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.views;

-- Loop through each view and get the RecordCount
OPEN viewCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM viewCursor INTO @viewName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO #ViewRecordCount (ViewName, RecordCount) ' +
               N'SELECT N''' + @viewName + ''', COUNT(*) FROM ' + @viewName;
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM viewCursor INTO @viewName;
END

CLOSE viewCursor;
DEALLOCATE viewCursor;

-- Query to get RecordCount and ColumnCount
SELECT
    v.name AS ViewName,
    vr.RecordCount,
    COUNT(c.name) AS ColumnCount
FROM sys.views v
LEFT JOIN #ViewRecordCount vr ON v.name = vr.ViewName
LEFT JOIN sys.columns c ON v.object_id = c.object_id
GROUP BY v.name, vr.RecordCount
ORDER BY ViewName;

DROP TABLE #ViewRecordCount;
```